# Enable native NTFS symbolic links for Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, mingw, symlink, ntfs, ln

Recent NTFS and Windows implement symlinks:

- [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) can be used as directory symlink since NTFS 3.0 (Windows 2000) using `linkd` or `junction` tools.
- [NTFS symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) can also be used as symlink (for both file and directory) since Windows Vista using `mklink` tool.

But on Cygwin 1.7 (installed on Windows 7), `ln -s` creates a text file.

on Cygwin:

```
$ ln -s -v target mylink
`mylink' -> `target'
```

on MinGW (or your favorite editor):

```
$ cat mylink
!<symlink>ÿþt a r g e t
```

**Is it possible to tell Cygwing to use [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) or [NTFS symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)?**

other question: **Is this available on MinGW?**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

## ⸻⸻  Short answer  ⸻⸻

Define environment variable:

```bash
CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict
```

As pointed out by [mwm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353752/mwm) you may also have to go to the settings or to run [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) as Administrator. See the **Notes** section.

## ⸻⸻  Long answer  ⸻⸻

### Default Cygwin symlinks are just regular files

By default [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) creates text files as workaround for Windows symlink flaw.
These files are not really [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).
Almost all Windows programs do not considers these files as symlinks.

### Native symlinks are available on recent Windows versions

Recent NTFS and Windows implement symlinks:

- [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) can be used as directory symlink
  since NTFS 3.0 (Windows 2000) using `linkd` or `junction` tools.
- [NTFS symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) can also be used as symlink
  (for both file and directory) since Windows Vista using `mklink` tool.

### Cygwin can create native [NTFS symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Simplified extract of the [Cygwin documentation](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks):

> ### Symbolic links
>
> [...]
>
> Cygwin creates symbolic links potentially in multiple different ways:
>
> - The default symlinks are plain files containing a magic cookie
>   followed by the path to which the link points. [...]
> - The shortcut style symlinks are Windows `.lnk` [...] created
>   if the environment variable CYGWIN [...] is set to contain
>   the string `winsymlinks` or `winsymlinks:lnk`. [...]
> - Native Windows symlinks are only created on Windows Vista/2008 and later,
>   and only on filesystems supporting reparse points.
>   Due to to their weird restrictions and behaviour, they are only created
>   if the user explicitely requests creating them.
>   This is done by setting the environment variable CYGWIN
>   to contain the string `winsymlinks:native` or `winsymlinks:nativestrict`.
>   [...]
> - On the NFS filesystem, Cygwin always creates real NFS symlinks.

### Configuring Cygwin

[Cygwin User's Guide](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html) presents variable `CYGWIN` and option `winsymlinks`:

> The `CYGWIN` environment variable is used to configure many global settings [...].
> It contains the options listed below, separated by blank characters. [...]
>
> - [...]
> - [...]
> - [...]
> - [...]
> - `winsymlinks:{lnk,native,nativestrict}` -
>   if set to just `winsymlinks` or `winsymlinks:lnk`, Cygwin creates symlinks
>   as Windows shortcuts with a special headerand the R/O attribute set.
>
>   If set to `winsymlinks:native` or `winsymlinks:nativestrict`,
>   Cygwin creates symlinks as native Windows symlinks on filesystems
>   and OS versions supporting them. If the OS is known not to support
>   native symlinks (Windows XP, Windows Server 2003), a warning message
>   is produced once per session.
>
>   The difference between `winsymlinks:native` and
>   `winsymlinks:nativestrict` is this: If the filesystem supports native
>   symlinks and Cygwin fails to create a native symlink for some reason,
>   it will fall back to creating Cygwin default symlinks with
>   `winsymlinks:native`, while with `winsymlinks:nativestrict`
>   the `symlink(2)` system call will immediately fail.

#### `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native` 
 always creates a link but uses a Cygwin fall-back when target does not exists

on Cygwin:

```bash
$ export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:native"
$ ln -s -v target mylink
`mylink' -> `target'
$ echo content > target
```

on MinGW:

```bash
$ cat mylink
content
```

People using both Windows and Cygwin programs may have issues when a symlink is created as a dummy file (Cygwin fallback when target is missing)...

#### `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict` 
 always uses native-Windows symlink but fails when target does not exist

on Cygwin:

```bash
$ export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:nativestrict"
$ rm -f  a b
$ ln -sv a b
ln: failed to create symbolic link `b': No such file or directory
$ touch    b
$ ln -sv a b
ln: failed to create symbolic link `b': File exists
$ rm b
$ touch a
$ ln -sv a b
`b' -> `a'
```

Because **`nativestrict`** requires the target exists before the symlink creation, some commands/scripts may fail when creating a link.

### Notes

Since Windows 10 build 14972, native NTFS symlinks are available in a non-elevated shell by enabling the **Developer Mode** in the **Developer Settings**.
Reference: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

In older versions, only administrators have the ability to create native NT symlinks
so under Windows UAC, the Cygwin terminal emulator (mintty)
should be run with elevated privileges
(right-click the shortcut and choose *Run as Administrator*
or set the mintty shortcut property, *Advanced → Run as Administrator*).

<sub>Special thanks to [Guria](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18660841/3), [Spooky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159643/spooky) and [Gene Pavlovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4377192/gene-pavlovsky) for their contributions.</sub>

Comment: I've just upvoted this very informative answer. I also added a suggested edit that users with UAC enabled should run mintty with elevated privileges to be able to create native NT symlinks.

Comment: export CYGWIN="winsymlinks:nativestrict" worked for me in Windows 8

Comment: For MSYS2, uncomment `set MSYS=winsymlinks:nativestrict` in `/msys2_shell.bat`.

Comment: This didn't work on my system. The only way was through `cmd /c ...`

Comment: Hi @CMCDragonkai. Thanks for your feedback but I do not know what to say as I do not have same issue. Please tell me what to update in the answer. Cheers ;-)

Comment: Inaccurate info on what `nativestrict` means. Quoting the [Cygwin User Guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html): *The difference between winsymlinks:native and winsymlinks:nativestrict is this: If the filesystem supports native symlinks and Cygwin fails to create a native symlink for some reason, it will fall back to creating Cygwin default symlinks with winsymlinks:native, while with winsymlinks:nativestrict the symlink(2) system call will immediately fail.*
Personally I'm using `nativestrict` and didn't have any fails so far.

Comment: Thank you @GenePavlovsky for your feedback :-) I have reworked the answer. However I do not have Cygwin on my computer for the moment (only native Linux). As soon as I install Cygwin, I will check again the snippets. What do you suggest? Cheers :-)

Comment: @olibre I've since switched to `native`, because in `nativestrict` mode attempting to create a symlink to non-existent file. E.g. I'm using Gentoo's `run-crons` script in Cygwin, that script creates a lockfile pointing to the current PID (`$$`), that fails in `nativestrict` mode. In `native` mode, it creates a Cygwin (non-native) symlink. I think this is a strange behavior and tried to report it as a bug on Cygwin mailing list, but it was dismissed. You can use that peculiarity to test `ln -s moo link` (assuming `moo` doesn't exist) will fail on `nativestrict` only.

Comment: Thank you @GenePavlovsky for your feedback :-) I am glad that `native` enables you to use `run-crons` script. I suppose this may be a design bug in NTFS or Windows internal stuff... Cheers ;-)

Comment: No, that's Cygwin's chosen behavior. Windows' `mklink` command can create such *broken* links without error.

Comment: Thank you @GenePavlovsky very much. I will update my answer. Cheers ;-)

Comment: It only works for me if it is run as administrator bash

Comment: You can set up permissions for creating symlinks, so you don't have to run as administrator. See: https://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user?answertab=votes#125981

Comment: On Windows, you might always want to use `nativestrict`, because you don't want Cygwin to fall back to the default behavior at all.

Comment: I wish the part about being unable to create symlinks that point to targets that don't exist was featured a little better or reworded slightly because I missed it and then went down a rabbit hole leading me right back here.
@GenePavlovsky You were the light at the end of the long tunnel - unfortunately, the Cygwin team didn't see it that way: https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin/2016-04/msg00658.html

Comment: Hi @EchoLynx. I need your help to improve my old original answer (2013). I am using Ubuntu at home and Fedora at work. My last computer on Windows was Windows 7. What should I change in this answer to reflect recent changes? Cheers, have fun 

Comment: @oHo On Windows 10, enable _Developer Mode_ in _Developer Settings_ to be able to creative native NTFS symlinks in a non-elevated shell. Reference: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you @GenePavlovsky  I have just updated the answer. Have a nice day 

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is right, two little side notes.

If you only care about the symlinks you create yourself on the command line, install `cygutils-extra` package, it includes a `winln` command, which has the same syntax as `ln`, but creates native Windows links. Create an alias: `alias ln=winln` (only works in interactive shell), or even replace the `ln` file with `winln` (works in shell scripts as well) - but it might get overwritten the next time `coreutils` package is updated.

I've only found out it's possible to use native symlinks when I already had Cygwin installed, and added some symlinks by myself as well. So after I set `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native` as my system environment variable, I wanted to convert all the existing non-native links to native. Here's what I did.

**Just in case, back up your entire Cygwin directory first.**

Find all symlinks and save the list to `/links` file:
`cd /; find . -regextype egrep -regex './(dev|proc|mnt|cygdrive)' -prune -o -type l -print >links`

Review `links`.
Create a `tar` archive with all the links: `tar c --files-from=links >links.tar`

Extract the `tar` archive: `tar x --files-from=links <links.tar`
Since native symlinks are now enabled, tar will overwrite the old Cygwin's symlinks with native symlinks.

Clean up: `rm -f links links.tar`

P.S. At first I used `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict`, but then I found out that in this mode, `ln -s target link` fails if `target` doesn't exist. By contrast, `native` will create a Cygwin (non-native) symlink `link` pointing to the nonexistent `target` - this matches the behavior of `ln` on UNIX systems. In rare cases, `nativestrict` can break some programs or scripts, for example Gentoo `run-crons` script uses a lockfile which is a symlink pointing to the PID of the running process. In `nativestrict` mode the script stopped working, because it could no longer create the lockfile. Note: `run-crons` is a crontab helper script on Gentoo Linux, adding support for `cron.{hourly,daily,weekly,monthly}/` dirs, it works very well with Cygwin.

Comment: While this does work (and first we need `editrights -u $USER -a SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`), this kind of symlink is not exactly the same as the symlink created by `mklink`. Basically CMD's `mklink` doesn't respect that privilege setting and CMD's `mklink` properly sets the type of file to ".symlink", while `winln` doesn't do this. The effect is basically that the symlinks actually look like symlinks when rendered by Windows Explorer and by Cygwin's `ls`, they know it to be a windows symlink when using `mklink`.

Comment: Are you talking about winln or the symlinks created by tar with `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict`. I didn't really use winln much, so can't comment, but in the latter case symlinks created by Cygwin look like symlinks in Explorer etc.

Comment: I'm talking about `winln`. Just tried it just then. The `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict` didn't work at all for me before.

Comment: Ok, I've just tried `mklink fzf-mklink fzf`, `winln -s fzf fzf-winln`, `ln -s fzf fzf-ln` (winsymlinks:nativestrict is set). All three links created show as `.symlink` type in Explorer and point to the same file, fzf. The only difference I can see is mklink-created link is owned by `BUILTIN\Administrators`, while both Cygwin-created links are owned by `Alpha\root` (the current user).
Does `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict` work for you now, or not? If not, how do you define that variable?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai On Windows 10, enable _Developer Mode_ in _Developer Settings_ to be able to creative native NTFS symlinks in a non-elevated shell. Reference: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

Answer (score 4):

Since @olibre answer didn't work for me. I just created a shell function.

```
: '
mklink - Create NTFS (Windows) links that is usable by Windows and Cygwin

Usage: mklink [/D | /H | /J] <link-path> <target-path>

Options:
    /D    Directory Symbolic Link
    /H    Hardlink
    /J    Directory Junction (you should prefer /D)

With no options, it creates a NTFS file symlink.
'
mklink () {

    if [ "$#" -ge "3" ]; then
        cmd /c mklink "$1" "$(cygpath --windows --absolute "$2")" "$(cygpath --windows --absolute "$3")"
    else
        cmd /c mklink "$(cygpath --windows --absolute "$1")" "$(cygpath --windows --absolute "$2")"
    fi

}
```

Do note you need administrator permissions (for Cygwin) to run the above without problems.

Note that I am unaware whether there's any difference between symlinking to an absolute path versus symlinking to a relative path using CMD's `mklink`. On Linux, those 2 have different behaviours if you ever decide to move the symlink or move the target file, or move both.

Comment: Nice alternative :-) Please provide Windows versions (and potentuially Cygwin/MinGW) on which you have tested your script to help other SO readers. Thanks ;-)

Comment: The `cygutils-extra` package includes a `winln` command which provides an `ln`-like syntax to create Windows native links.

Comment: Ah that tool is great. It even suggests: `editrights -a SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege -a $YOUR_USER`.

Comment: But it should be `editrights -u $USER -a SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` actually.

Comment: Didn't suggest it to me since I'm working as an administrator.

Comment: Great tip for running mklink from cygwin (cmd /c mklink), thanks!

Comment: @CMCDragonkai On Windows 10, enable _Developer Mode_ in _Developer Settings_ to be able to creative native NTFS symlinks in a non-elevated shell. Reference: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to

1. grant [SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2094663/938111) from Local Group Policy editor (gpedit.msc, on path by default, non-home versions)
2. create script named `ln` on path (batch or bash), implementation
   similar to above described shell function
3. profit

Answer (score -5):

You were probably looking for a way to get to another destination in catalogue tree using MSYS. There is a way. You should create a shell script ("*.sh" file) which contains line:

```
cd "/drive_letter/SubCatalogue/SubFolder/..."
```

Comment: Hi FreeCodeRide. Thanks for your idea but I am not sure to understand. Please provide an example. For instance, you may create a target file, then a file linked to this target file... Cheers ;)