# Share .mailmap or other top-level files between multiple Git repositories, cross-platform

Tags: linux, windows, git, cross-platform, git-submodules

I have a number of Git repositories with similar contributors. Over the lifetime of those repositories, most contributors have used a variety of email addresses, etc. As such, each repository has a `.mailmap` file to facilitate `git shortlog -s -e`.

Because these `.mailmap` files are nearly identical to each other, the existing situation is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). And each time a contributor adopts a new email address or suchlike, a new alias needs to be added across all the `.mailmap` files in all the repositories they are contributing to.

I would like to factor the `.mailmap` files out into a single repository (let's call it `mailmap`), so that new aliases only need to be added in *one* place, that will propagate to all the other repositories.

Using a `git submodule` called `mailmap`, with a symbolic link in each other repository from `.mailmap` to `mailmap/.mailmap`, seems like a reasonable option, but will the symbolic link work on Windows? I.e. will `git shortlog -s -e` show the same thing on Windows as it does on POSIX systems? (The current contributors don't use Windows, but Windows users might clone the Git repositories, and we want `git shortlog -s -e` to work for them as well as it works for us.)

If not, what might be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the symbolic links work on Windows, there are several possibilities, including:

- Ensure that Windows users use [GNU/kWindows](https://mikegerwitz.com/2016/04/GNU-kWindows) (aka [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)).
- Ensure that Windows users use [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) with [elevated privileges and either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18659632) `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict` or `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:native`.
- Ensure that Windows users manually (or perhaps automatically via a hook) [replace POSIX symlinks with Windows equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754068).