# XSym symbolic links cannot be used in PHP on Docker for Windows

Tags: php, docker, windows-10, samba, ddev

When using PHP inside a Docker container on Windows (e.g. using DDEV), symbolic links that are created inside the container (e.g. by composer) do not seem to work correctly with PHP's file streams.

### Scenario

Imagine the following PHP code

```
<?php
mkdir('demo-base-directory');
symlink('demo-base-directory', 'demo-symbolic-link');
var_dump(glob('demo-*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
```

If executed inside the container, it outputs only `demo-base-directory`, however `demo-symbolic-link` is missing (the very same example works as expected on Linux/Unix systems inside Docker containers)

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "demo-base-directory"
}
```

When viewing the symbolic link in the host system (e.g. using `cat demo-symbolic-link` in Windows PowerShell) it shows

```
XSym
0019
0df68e8650ddca993c28277a5cfa3dcd
demo-base-directory
```

There have been other reports to Docker for Windows about symlink emulation - I could not reproduce this behavior for files using `fgets` or `file_get_contents` but for the mentioned `glob` invocation, see

- https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/137
- https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1283

Shared volumes are mounted in a Linux-based Docker container on a Windows host system as Samba/CIFS mount like this:

> //10.0.75.1/C on /var/www/html type cifs
>   (rw,relatime,vers=3.02,sec=ntlmsspi,cache=strict,username=olly,domain=OLIVERHADERB9D8,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=10.0.75.1,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,nounix,serverino,mapposix,nobrl,mfsymlinks,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)

Mount option `mfsymlinks` refers to [Minshall+French symlinks](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions#Minshall.2BFrench_symlinks)

### Workaround

Instead of creating symbolic links inside the container, creating them **outside** (directly in Windows) solves the problem.

#### Using plain [mklink in cmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink)

```
del demo-symbolic-link
mklink /d demo-symbolic-link demo-base-directory
```

output

```
symbolic link created for demo-symbolic-link <<===>> demo-base-directory
```

#### Using plain mklink via cmd in PowerShell

```
del demo-symbolic-link
cmd /c mklink /d demo-symbolic-link demo-base-directory
```

output

```
symbolic link created for demo-symbolic-link <<===>> demo-base-directory
```

*side note: `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink` could not be resolved using `glob(..., GLOB_ONLYDIR in PHP` - using `mklink /d` here as well*

#### Using Git-Bash for Windows

I had to execute the following while executing Git-Bash as administrator. Setting the environment variable with `export` is important here - see [Enable native NTFS symbolic links for Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654162/enable-native-ntfs-symbolic-links-for-cygwin/18659632#18659632)

```
rm demo-symbolic-link
export MSYS=winsymlinks:nativestrict
ln -s demo-base-directory/ demo-symbolic-link
```

#### Helper tools

I've created helper tool examples that search for Samba `XSym` pointers in a particular directory (TYPO3 related, `public/typo3conf/ext/`) and "upgrade" the XSym pointers to proper symlinks - probably admin privileges are required when executing those scripts:

- [BAT helper to be used in cmd.exe](https://gist.github.com/ohader/f4b792e0bb99e79efe75605008ce4a0d#file-use-native-symlinks-bat)
- [BASH helper to be used in Git-Bash](https://gist.github.com/ohader/f4b792e0bb99e79efe75605008ce4a0d#file-use-native-symlinks-sh)

### Results

Executing the PHP example from above again now outputs both expected items

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "demo-base-directory"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "demo-symbolic-link"
}
```

### Question

Working inside a Docker container and having to adjust symbolic links manually on the host system is really just a workaround - not a solution. At which level could this be enhanced and optimized in order to create proper symbolic links using the Docker container only?

It seems this could be resolved at different layers:

- [PHP's `glob` invocation](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/eff22dc511d677d12097018da630971d730b70f9/ext/standard/dir.c#L471) (especially for flaky `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag)
- [glibc's `glob` implementation](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/glob.c;h=8444b2f79e3b2edb09a47cfa03fc4ae469e8a188;hb=HEAD#l287) (especially for [Minshall+French symlinks](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/UNIX_Extensions#Minshall.2BFrench_symlinks) `XSym`)
- Docker not using Samba/CIFS for volume sharing

---

*Updates*

- switched from `mklink /j` (junction) to `mklink /d` (symlinked directory) since removing the linked junction removed it's origin as well
- PowerShell's symlink cmdlet `New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink` (instead of previous `New-Item -ItemType Junction`) then again could not be resolved using `glob(..., GLOB_ONLYDIR` in PHP - as a result, using `cmd /c mklink /d` here
- added Samba/CIFS mount information

Comment: Thanks for the great work on this here and on https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1283 - I'm confident we're  going to get this sorted out and get predictable behavior for Windows people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with ddev v1.5.0, the `ddev composer` command on Windows attempts to convert XSym symlinks to legitimate Windows symlinks. This feature only works if you have enabled "Developer mode" on Windows. See [Windows OS and ddev composer](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/developer-tools/#ddev-and-composer) in docs.

Comment: Thanks for integrating this solution into DDEV! Basically the problem is located in PHP and some inconsistencies there (e.g. using `glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR)`). Great you provided a solution for that! :+1:

Comment: Also, in recent versions of ddev nfsmount_enabled completely works around this, as the symlinks are OK in the first place. But nfsmount_enabled requires some work in advance to set up the local NFS server. https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/performance/#windows-nfs-setup