# In Python from Cygwin, os.symlink not creating proper Symlink

Tags: python, windows, cygwin

Based on below code, I am trying to create symlink from Cygwin command prompt. It generates a symlink file but it seems not valid windows symlink.

Below code works fine and generates proper symlink if I run the same code from native command prompt.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Feb 14 2019, 22:09:48)
[GCC 7.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.symlink("package.jpg", "sample.jpg")
>>>
```

Comment: It is possible to configure Cygwin to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654162/enable-native-ntfs-symbolic-links-for-cygwin/18659632#18659632

Comment: Per Kyrylo Shpytsya: possible duplicate of [Enable native NTFS symbolic links for Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654162/enable-native-ntfs-symbolic-links-for-cygwin)

Comment: I cannot say the question is duplicate because people facing issue like me will not have idea to "Enable native NTFS symbolic links for Cygwin"