# How to follow a filepath specified within a text file on Cygwin?

Tags: linux, cygwin, filepath, kaldi

I'm trying to run some Kaldi examples after I have compiled it on Cygwin, however, when the directory is specified in a file, Cygwin can't follow it. For example, I am trying to run the following in Cygwin terminal:

```
steps/make_mfcc.sh
```

This returns:

```
No such file or directory
```

This makes sense, since `steps` is not a directory, but a file with the following content:

```
../../wsj/s5/steps/
```

Which leads to `steps` directory which is what I need, and if I manually point it to the correct place, it works fine, but then breaks when a similar approach to pointing to a directory is used.

I have tried compiling Kaldi on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and running the same example, and everything worked perfectly, which leads me to believe that it's a Cygwin issue.

Is there a way to make it work as it does on Ubuntu?

PS. I know using Kaldi on Cygwin is not the best option, especially since I'm new to Cygwin, but as far as I'm aware it's the only one which doesn't involve having a Linux VM which I can't do. If there are better ways of using Kaldi on Windows, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable native NTFS symbolic links for Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654162/enable-native-ntfs-symbolic-links-for-cygwin)

Comment: You just need to configure symlinks to work in Cygwin. Overall, Cygwin is a path of pain and continuous troubles, you'd better install Linux in Virtualbox.